# Why isn't the Kotlin tag icon the same as the current official Kotlin icon?

Tags: discussion, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

Recently, in a scope of two weeks, the [Kotlin tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) icon changed from the [Kotlin icon](https://kotlinlang.org/assets/images/open-graph/kotlin_250x250.png) to blank to the current, I do not know what it is, but it looks like an old icon maybe.

[image: Current Kotlin tag with icon]

My question is how to see the icon changes, like you can see the question and answer edit history. I would be very interested in the reasons for these changes. I know I and probably not even moderators can change an icon, but does this change really make sense? Could someone give insights on this? The official Kotlin "icon usage" guidelines can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#where-can-i-get-an-hd-kotlin-icon). It clearly displays how the previous icon

[image: Previous (correct) Kotlin tag icon in a Tweet from @kotlin on Twitter] [source](https://twitter.com/kotlin/status/913413738971193345)

should have been kept? Why should *Kotlin* pay money to replace an icon that they prefer with one that I did never find in any official document?

### In a nutshell

How can one get insight into tag icon changes?

*Additional:* I know that these represent branding and purchased, but someone has to put them on and I do not entirely understand why this should happen, I am aware that as [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) moderators cannot change them, but maybe they have insights on it? I think the discussion tag really matches this question because it looks like the icons are not really community related.

Comment: The images are provided by the company sponsoring the tag; we don't go looking for them or choose them ourselves. The ads team has been pinged as maybe they'd have more information about why the icon got changed.

Comment: @animuson But why should they do something like this, makes no sense to me? Could it be possible that others (other than the actual company, here JetBrains) are able to to sponsor an icon?

Comment: It could just be an oversight, maybe someone uploaded the wrong logo. According to Google, they definitely did use that logo at some point. But only the ads team can answer what happened, or reach out to them to confirm this is what they wanted to use. As well, only the owner of the product is allowed to sponsor the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These changes took place over the last week as we were updating an advertising campaign for a client. For a brief moment, we were using the old kotlin logo, but that has been corrected. Any changes we make to tag logos are at the request of the clients sponsoring the tag. If they were to update their style guide during this campaign, we would switch out the old logos with the new.

Comment: Does that mean that the icon will change again in the near feature, because it did not yet for me?

Comment: There is sometimes a short delay, so if you are still seeing the old logo, you will indeed see it change again to the new logo. I would recommend clearing your cache and revisiting the page if you are still seeing the old logo for more than a few hours.